# icCube : Geo Chart limiting region not working

Tags: google-maps, iccube, iccube-reporting

Specifying the "Region" in a Google Geo Chart does not limit the map to the given region but instead is generating an error about the requested map not existing. I'd like to limit the map to the Europe region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google might have changed the way it works since early version of icCube. Having a look to this Google documentation [www](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#configuration-options), Europe is referenced as 150.